# Divergence of Harmonic Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, harmonic-numbers

I understand that the divergence of the harmonic series is a classic proof but what I don't understand is the way it seems to contradict standard methods of finding if a series converges or not.

For the series $\Sigma \frac{1}{n}$ as $n$ approaches infinity it would seem that $\frac{1}{n}$ would tend to $0$. We know this isn't the case though but why is this seemingly standard procedure wrong? Is there some extra proof that must be shown other than just inserting $n$ for infinity?

Comment: $\frac1n$ *does* tend to $0$; that would be necessary but not sufficient for $\Sigma \frac1n$ to converge

Comment: I had thought that if $\frac{1}{n}$ was shown to tend to 0, then that would mean there would exist some limit that the series converges on (as each term would become so small as to tend to 0 eventually).

Comment: No, terms tending to zero doesn't mean the series converges (though if the terms didn't tend to zero, the series certainly would not converge); cf. [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test)

Answer (score 1):

If the terms of a series do not approach $0$, then the series diverges.

If the terms of a series do approach $0$, then the series may or may not converge.

The harmonic series is an example of a series that does not converge though the terms approach $0$.

See  [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).